# Prove multidimensional Newton's method converge at least quadratically

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Newton's method for root finding is simply $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$. The following is a theorem from my textbook.

> [image]
>
> where 6.1.22 is shown below
> [image]

**Now I want to prove a similar claim for multidimensional newton on a function** $F:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$, which is ${{\bf{x}}_{n + 1}} = {{\bf{x}}_n} - {J^{( - 1)}}({{\bf{x}}_n})F({{\bf{x}}_n})$ where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F(\bf{x})$. My attempt is as following. I got stuck at the step colored red. **I need to cancel all the $\bf{\epsilon}$ and only keeps the Jacobian and Hessian matrices**. Can anyone give some help on this? Thank you!

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:If $A$ is a continuous function with values in the positive definite matrices, then for every $z$ there is a neighborhood of $z$ and a constant $C$ such that if $y$ is in that neighborhood and $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then
$$
v^TA(y)v\leq Cv^Tv.
$$
Applying this with $(J^{-1})^TJ^{-1}$ and then with $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_n$ should get you there.

(By the way, the statement is not quite precise (with this proof at least): you need the second derivative to be continuous, and start the iteration from sufficiently close)